# Reg. /etc/network/interfaces file

Tags: networking

I want to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` file which was working with wired LAN. It was edited to work with wifi having deleting a line from it. Now the whole thing is not working with either i.e. wired LAN or with wifi. Please help me, can I edit that file (inserting the same line at it's place previously) on windows PC and then put it to work with Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Yes, you can. Try it, and let us know how it works out.

Comment: How? I mean tell me the procedure, please.

Comment: Take the SD-card out of the raspberry pi, insert it into your windows computer, edit the file, save it, remove the card from your windows computer, reinsert it into the pi, and reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you can not edit that file from a windows computer easily. Its on its own partition that windows can not see.

Your best bet is to edit the file from the PI its self using this command

`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

Make the changes you want i.e put in the missing line

Then ctrl + O then press enter to save the file

Then ctrl + X to exit

Then restart the pi.